# how to createTag in django-autocomplete-light

Tags: jquery-select2, django-autocomplete-light

I tried customizing the javascript loading as described at https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#overriding-javascript-code

but I do not see how to provide a callback for the createTag event as described at https://select2.org/tagging#customizing-tag-creation

Any help?

my code

```
# forms.py
class TickerWidget(autocomplete.ListSelect2):
    autocomplete_function = "ticker_autocomplete_init"


class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ["ticker"]
        widgets = {
            "ticker": TickerWidget(
                url="tickers",
                attrs={
                    "data-ajax-delay": "250",
                    "required": True,
                    "data-tags": "true",
                },
            )
        }
```

and

```
// app.js
document.addEventListener('dal-init-function', function () {
  yl.registerFunction('ticker_autocomplete_init', function ($, element) {
      var $element = $(element);
      // autocomplete function here
      console.log('I dont see this');
  });
})
```

Comment: Can you paste generated HTML and JS tracebacks if any.

Comment: Can you try adding console.logs before and after the addEventListener line too ?

Comment: I made a full example at https://github.com/morenoh149/djangox-autocomplete-light/blob/master/static/js/base.js please try running it and explain how to pass the createTag callback. I see the console log before the addEventListener but not on the inside on line 7.

Comment: I'm sorry Harry, but your running your test project in my browser does show all the console.log statements ... and have attached a screenshot on your github pr ... I can't reproduce the behavior you mean with the test project.

Comment: @jpic its fine I solved this part. Now I have a purely select2 question if you are interested https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64722399/show-item-request-form-when-an-unknown-item-is-selected-in-select2

Comment: Good job Harry ! Do you know what was the problem exactly ? I'll pass on select2, haven't looked in a long time you've seen the alternative I have on github :P

Comment: I think the issue was lack of a more complete example. I found it difficult to understand your example code in the repo. Hopefully my demo helps others.

Comment: Not to mention the bugs ! Thank you for documenting this on StackOverflow !  Keep up the gr888 work ;)

Answer (score 0):

I kept working on it and eventually figured out how to override the callbacks on select2.

```
# forms.py

class TickerWidget(autocomplete.ListSelect2):
    autocomplete_function = "ticker_autocomplete_init"


class CompanyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ["ticker"]
        widgets = {
            "ticker": TickerWidget(
                url="company-autocomplete",
            )
        }
```

and in js

```
document.addEventListener('dal-init-function', function () {
    yl.registerFunction('ticker_autocomplete_init', function ($, element) {
        console.log('baz');
        
        var $element = $(element);
        $element.select2({
            placeholder: 'Company',
            ajax: {
                url: "/company-autocomplete",
                delay: 250,
            },
            createTag: function(params) {
                console.log('createTag', params);
                return {
                    id: params.term,
                    text: params.term.toUpperCase(),
                }
            },
            tags: true,
            insertTag: function(data, tag) {
                tag.text = "Add: " + tag.text;
                // tag.isTag = true;
                data.push(tag);
            },
        });
        $element.on("change:selecting", function(e) {
            console.log('select');
            if (e.params && e.params.data) {

                var data = e.params.data;
                var requestForm = document.querySelector('#form-ticker-request');
                if (data.isTag) {
                    console.log('local tag selected', data);
                    requestForm.classList.remove('d-none');
                } else {
                    requestForm.classList.add('d-none');
                }
            }
        });
    });
  })
```

code is viewable at https://github.com/morenoh149/djangox-autocomplete-light